# Selecting the transaction, showing one row only but has multiple rows in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net

In this void, I have selected the transaction. Example there are 3 rows in the database that has a PONo of 17, I want to show only one row in the list view. Is it possible?

```
void GetSupply()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Supplier.SupplierName, PurchaseOrder.PONo, PurchaseOrder.PODate, " +
        "PurchaseOrder.PODateReceived, PurchaseOrder.PODeliveryDate, PurchaseOrder.POPaymentMethod, " +
        "PurchaseOrder.POReceiptNo, PurchaseOrderDetails.POAmount, PurchaseOrder.POPaymentDate, " +
        "PurchaseOrder.POStatus FROM PurchaseOrder INNER JOIN PurchaseOrderDetails " +
        "ON PurchaseOrder.PONo = PurchaseOrderDetails.PONo INNER JOIN Supplier ON " +
        "PurchaseOrder.SupplierNo = Supplier.SupplierID " +
        "ORDER BY PurchaseOrder.PODate DESC";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "PurchaseOrderDetails");
    lvPO.DataSource = ds;
    lvPO.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

It looks like this for now

[image]

I want to show it like this

[image]

Comment: simply use distinct in query `SELECT DISTINCT ....`

Comment: the other way Select Top 1

Comment: I cannot use top 1, because the are few more existing than needs to be shown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use `select DISTINCT` ie,

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT Supplier.SupplierName, PurchaseOrder.PONo, PurchaseOrder.PODate, " +
        "PurchaseOrder.PODateReceived, PurchaseOrder.PODeliveryDate, " +
        "FROM PurchaseOrder INNER JOIN PurchaseOrderDetails " +
        "ON PurchaseOrder.PONo = PurchaseOrderDetails.PONo INNER JOIN Supplier ON " +
        "PurchaseOrder.SupplierNo = Supplier.SupplierID " +
        "ORDER BY PurchaseOrder.PODate DESC";
```

or try to use GROUP BY

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Supplier.SupplierName, PurchaseOrder.PONo, PurchaseOrder.PODate, " +
        "PurchaseOrder.PODateReceived, PurchaseOrder.PODeliveryDate, " +
        "FROM PurchaseOrder INNER JOIN PurchaseOrderDetails " +
        "ON PurchaseOrder.PONo = PurchaseOrderDetails.PONo INNER JOIN Supplier ON " +
        "PurchaseOrder.SupplierNo = Supplier.SupplierID " +
        "GROUP BY PurchaseOrder.PONo,Supplier.SupplierName, PurchaseOrder.PODateReceived, PurchaseOrder.PODeliveryDate ORDER BY PurchaseOrder.PODate DESC";
```

Comment: how do I make a distinct statement?

Comment: @gamered123:- I have added the query in my answer. You can use that.

Comment: I have put it, but it still occupy 3 rows

Comment: @gamered123:- Try to use `SELECT TOP 1 Supplier.SupplierName, PurchaseOrder.PONo,..........`

Comment: top 1 cannot be used, because I also need to show different transactions. I just want to eliminates duplicates

Comment: @gamered123:- which database you are using?

Comment: @gamered123:- Also on which column you are categorizing the value as duplicates?

Comment: I'm using an sql server

Comment: The PONo? I just want to show one PONo. 17 in the list

Comment: The reason why it shows all 3 rows with the DISTINCT is because any of the other fields in the SELECT is different in all 3 rows. If you just want those 4  fields shown in your question (SupplierName, PONo and the 3 dates), only select those fields.

Comment: I have done the group by, but is shows an error: Column 'Supplier.SupplierName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. What does this mean

Comment: @gamered123:- You need to provide the column names in the GROUP BY function which you are selecting.

Comment: @Ryaden I have done what you suggested. It works properly